# How can Trepp use the same type of sleeve on different worlds?

Tags: altered-carbon

In the beginning of season 2 of Netflix series *Altered Carbon*, we meet bounty hunter Trepp as she tracks down Takeshi Kovacs (presumably, still on Earth (?)). She manages to capture him and his mind is sent off-world, needlecast to another Harlan's World.

Later on, we see that Trepp has been transferred to Harlan's World, as well. There, she is wearing a sleeve that looks the same as the one from the opening scene on Earth.

**How is that possible?**

My impression was that sleeves are somewhat valuable. Custom sleeves, clones of one's own body, appeared to be somewhat of a priviledge only wealthy meths could afford (although Kovacs somehow procured a device that was capable of instant cloning once in season 1). In particular, Trepp's sleeve is not simply "grown", but also as cybernetic enhancements.

Is her getting that sleeve a favour by whoever paid her to track down Kovacs? Or is she using some kind of a "standard model" of a sleeve that is available on different worlds (but then, how is it that no-one else wears the same sleeve)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She is using a [synthetic sleeve](https://altered-carbon.fandom.com/wiki/Synth) on the other planet, which provides a cheaper/easier way to get the same appearance. I assume the coils here are just for show.

When Trepp tastes her drink at the bar, she remarks on how poor her synth sleeve's taste buds are.

To Poe:

> Trepp: It's not you. The nerve endings in this thing are for shit
>
> Poe: You're wearing a synth
>
> Trepp: More like a latex glove

Comment: Ok, I suppose combined with the aspect that synthetic sleeves essentially make you a shapeshifter (which, I think, was not in the books, where - if I recall correctly - at least some synthetic sleeves would actually look distinctly *synthetic*) it somehow makes sense that we don't see plenty of people wearing this model of synthetic sleeve running around.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Presumably you buy a custom future-latex skin for your synth in the shape you want, which is again presumably still much much quicker/cheaper than growing a clone. My memories of the books are a bit hazy, but I think that there were a range of qualities when it came to synths, and the cheap ones certainly looked obvious. Theres certainly a lot more handwaving of this stuff in the show.